# SSIS package cannot see network drive

Tags: networking, sql-server, io, ssms, ssis

I have an SSIS package  that cannot see a network folder (with files) - when run directly from SSMS. (Windows Server 2019, SQL Server 2019, Visual Studio 2019, SSMS versions 17 & 18). I am using a UNC path to the folder.

If I run the same SSIS package in Visual Studio, it can see the folders - and it works. If I execute the package from a SQL Job (with a proxy from the same Windows User), it works.  The package just will not run correctly when launched from SSMS... and yes, I am logged into SSMS with Windows Authentication.

If I move the network folder to a local drive (on the SQL Server server) it works inside of SSMS as well, just not on the network. I have tried running SSMS "as Administrator" - no difference.

There is something about the security context that SSMS/SSIS is running in - that has it using a Windows user/service that cannot access the network. In some cases I just get the following warning:

*"The ForEach File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty"*

In other cases I get this error:
*"Access to the path is denied"*.

Any ideas?